# Position child element outside its context in Bourbon Neat

Tags: grid, bourbon, neat, margin

I'm trying to change the context of an html children element.

```
<div class="outer-container">
   <div class="main-content">
     <img class="chid-element" />
   </div>
</div>
```

The `main-content`element is 6 columns wide and is shifted by 2.
I would like its children `<img>`to span from the .outer container's second column to its 11th.

[image: My layout]

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: were you ever able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `chid-element` you need to use `@include span-columns(10 of 8)` and `@include shift(-1)`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpQZgy